# cakephp update multiple div

Tags: cakephp, html

I am trying to update multiple divs using ajax in cakephp with no luck.
I followed some tutorials
http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2006/06/29/how-to-update-multiple-divs-with-ajax/
http://www.reversefolds.com/articles/show/ajax

but it still does not work on firefox 3.5.2

i am doing:

in view 
    echo $ajax->link('link text', '/controller/update', 
                 array('update' => array('div1', 'div2'))
                );

```
// create the div code rather than hard-coding <div id='div1'>
echo $ajax->div('div1');
echo $ajax->divEnd('div1');

echo $ajax->div('div2');
echo $ajax->divEnd('div2');
```

in controller:
    function update() { $this->layout = 'ajax'; }

what am i missing? i am using cakephp 1.2.3.8166

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was finally working..I followed http://www.reversefolds.com/articles/show/ajax to the letter and it worked!